# Unwanted / Unclicked object increment by itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, imageview

I have a problem, I am using for to print json data and using array list, but when I clicked 0th array, the 5th and 10th increment by itself, only the display changed, not the real amount...

[image]

[image]

Here's the example, I clicked the egg button, and then I scrolled down until find the 5th array also displaying the "1" amount, the same problem when I scroll until 10th array, and I thought every 5th array it gets error.. but the rest (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc doesn't get the error, as you can see, the 1st array = bread still blank)

Here is the code that you guys might help

```
import UIKit
struct Nutritionmenu
{
    static var data:Array<String> = Array <String>()
}
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var leftlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var qtytext: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var decrease: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageheader: UIImageView!
    var value = 0
    var check:Bool = false
    var idx = 0
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.decrease.userInteractionEnabled = true
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        qtytext.resignFirstResponder()
        self.endEditing(true)

    }
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let touch: UITouch? = touches.first as? UITouch
        if(touch?.view == myImageView)
        {
            value += 1
            qtytext.text = String(value)
            //println(qtytext.text)
        }
        if(touch?.view == decrease)
        {
            if(value >= 1)
            {
                value -= 1;

            }
            qtytext.text = String(value)
            let myquantity = qtytext.text
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myquantity, forKey: "SavedStringKey")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            qtytext.text = stringKey.stringForKey("SavedStringKey")

        }
        var data = Nutritiondata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var temp:Nutritiondata
        temp = data
        var idx = 0
        if(temp.amount-1 > 0) {
            temp.amount -= 1
        }
        data = Nutritiondata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        var tempJson = JSONSerializer.toJson(temp)
        for(var i = 0; i < Nutritionmenu.data.count; i++){
            if(Nutritionmenu.data[i] == tempJson){
                self.check = true
                self.idx = i
            }
        }
        if(!self.check) {
           Nutritionmenu.data.append(json)
        }
        else{
            Nutritionmenu.data[self.idx] = json
        }
    }
    func setCell(leftlabeltext: String, rightlabeltext: String, imagename: String)
    {
        self.leftlabel.text = leftlabeltext
        self.rightlabel.text = rightlabeltext
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imagename)

    }



}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
        let menu = arrayOfMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(menu.type, rightlabeltext: menu.unit, imagename: menu.image)
        var data = Nutritiondata(type: menu.type, amount: String(cell.value ).toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        JSONNutrisi.jsondata = json
        return cell
    }
```

this is my menu function

```
class Nutritiondata
{
    var type = "type"
    var amount = 0
    //var date = "Date"
    init (type: String, amount: Int)
    {
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
        //self.date = date
    }
}
```

i just find out the problem is the table doesn't make a new array instead reuse it, so when i click the 0th array, 5th array also increase, 1st array 6th also increase and so on.but how to fix it?

Comment: Please show your cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation.

Comment: edited the code.. is that what you mean? @RoyNakum

Comment: Please log your `menu`. Is `menu` having updated data?

Comment: @RoyNakum already edited the code, but i think that menu doesn't affect anything

Comment: That is the issue here. You should update `menu` when data is updated.

Comment: how to do that update sir ? @RoyNakum

Comment: Data is updated in touchesEnded method, right?

Comment: yes, that method works when button clicked, changing the value, but i still don't get if that method can affect the other row that i didn't click.. @RoyNakum

Comment: It is tableviewCell reuse problem. You have updated value at first cell, but actually the fifth cell is not newly created. It is reused. So, you must have the updated menu array to show counts.

Comment: i agree with you, i just found that 1st array also affect the 6th array..2nd - 7th..but i still don't know how to make the table make the new array instead reuse the table..:/ I'm on internship and never using swift before .. but thanks for the help.. @RoyNakum

Answer (score 0):

On select, you are changing the cell's value. So, when it's reused by TableView it's showing an available cell from memory. Then it has the value you have incremented. You should keep 'cell.value' thing in an array that has a relationship with arrayOfMenu indexes. Cells shouldn't be used to hold data.

Comment: but i think cell.value only describe how much you clicked the button, and shows the amount when i println..hmm (?)